# Create custom oscillator with long periodic wave

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, waveform

I'm trying to create a complex periodic sound with long period. I want to define frequencies as accurately as I can, so I'm using step `sampleRate*0.5/tableLen`. But I have some issues with large wave tables. The sound becomes distorted and loses high frequencies.

Here is a minimal example with ~440 Hz sine wave. When I use table with length 8192, the resulting sine wave is quite recognizable:

https://jsfiddle.net/zxqzntf0/

```
var gAudioCtx = new AudioContext();
var osc = gAudioCtx.createOscillator();
var tableSize = 8192;
var real = new Float32Array(tableSize);
var imag = new Float32Array(tableSize);
var freq = 440;
var step = gAudioCtx.sampleRate*0.5/tableSize;
real[Math.floor(freq/step)] = 1;
var wave = gAudioCtx.createPeriodicWave(real, imag, {disableNormalization: true});
osc.frequency.value = step;
osc.setPeriodicWave(wave);
osc.connect(gAudioCtx.destination);
osc.start();
```

But when I increase my table size, I'm getting something strange. Result is not a sine wave at all!

https://jsfiddle.net/0cc75nnm/

This problem reproduces in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge), so it doesn't seem to be a browser bug. But I've found nothing about this in documentation.

**Added**

I found that if oscillator frequency is a whole number >= 2 Hz, I have no any artifacts in resulting sound with table size 16384. I think it is quite acceptable for my needs for now. But someday I may want to create longer periods. If someone explains me why I get sound artifacts when step is less than 2 Hz, I will accept his answer.

There is an example of a complex sound melody that I generate in JavaScript:
https://jsfiddle.net/h9rfzrnL/1/

Answer (score 3):

You're creating you periodic waves incorrectly.  When filling the arrays for the periodic wave, assume the sample rate is 1.  Then if you want an oscillator at a frequency of 440 Hz, set the oscillator frequency to 440 Hz.

Thus, for a sine wave, the real array should be all zeroes and the imaginary array is [0, 1]. (You're actually creating a cosine wave, but that doesn't really matter too much.)

Comment: I want 20 sines in range 400-480 Hz, 40 sines in range 800-960 Hz and so on. I can't do it if I have 440 Hz step. Single sine wave is a minimal example of my problem.

Comment: Maybe a concrete example of the wave you want to create would help explain the issue better.  Still, the basic idea is to design your wave as if the sample rate were 1 Hz.  Then set the frequency of the oscillator as the base frequency of the desired signal.

Comment: I need harmonics that are distributed in some frequency range. So how can I create oscillator with frequencies 400, 401, ..., 480, 800, 801, ..., 960, 1200, 1201, ..., 1920, ... ... ..., 12800, 12801, ..., 15360? I can't do it, if I have step 440, I need step 1 Hz and very big table. Lesser step is better.

Comment: Where does this complex periodic signal come from? Is it really described as a bunch of frequencies?  If so, it might just be easiest to create a whole bunch of oscillators at the desired frequencies.  Not the best solution if you have a ton of oscillators.

Comment: I generate this signal procedurally in my JS code. Simple sine harmonics sound too artificial, but "wide" harmonics sound warmer and more pleasant. Do you suggest to create 5000 sine oscillators for example above? It is not a solution at all.

Comment: 5000 oscillators is not a great solution.  So, you have some periodic time-domain signal available?  Why not just compute the FFT (carefully) and use that for the periodic wave coefficients?

Comment: I have no any time domain source signals. I generate my signal in frequency domain from scratch then I play it.

Comment: Then I think you're stuck with what you're doing.  But I would set the oscillator frequency to 1.  Then the 400'th coefficient will represent a frequency of 400 Hz, as you want.

Comment: I've updated my question. Compare oscillator frequency 2 Hz (https://jsfiddle.net/abj11s40/) with oscillator frequency 1 Hz: (https://jsfiddle.net/p51w2baa/). First one works well. Second one adds some strange harmonic. Frequency of 0.5 Hz is even worse. Or maybe this problem exists only on my computer? I will test it on other computers tomorrow.

Comment: Looks like an implementation bug in Chrome. (Didn't check any other browser.)

Comment: In Firefox the problem is same, but it reproduces with a smaller value of step: https://jsfiddle.net/rtrw9e0m/

Comment: I do think that oscillators are optimized for audio frequency values so any oscillator frequency below 20 Hz or so may not be well supported.  I think the solution now is to do the math and compute the Fourier coefficients from the signal you have and use that in the periodic wave.